# Can the list of Divyadesams be added to or subtracted from?

Tags: temple, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, pilgrimage

Can new Divaydesams be created and/or existing ones derecognised as such?

Comment: No, they can't.  The Divya Desams are the 108 sacred places of Vishnu mentioned in the poems of the Alwars.  Since the Alwars' poems are fixed, so is the list of Divya Desams.

Answer (score 4):

Divyadeshams are the sacred places for all the Sri Vaishnavas.

The list can be only increased or decreased when the alwars and their poems are increased or decreased. Divyadesam is a place to which Alwars have sung the praise of Lord Vishnu's form ( this can be any of the five forms) present there. There are 108 Divyadesams for which Alwars have sung praise in their poems. 106 are present on earth and two are not. They are the milky ocean and Paramapadam, the highest abode of Lord Vishnu. Singing the praise of the Lord and compiling the Nalayira Divyaprabandham are the important reasons Alwar were born. As the task is completed, there wouldn't be new alwars similarly no new Divyadeshams too. I explained the reasons why there are 12 alwars and not anymore new alwars in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19917/5212)  answer of mine. As there are no new alwars, there wouldn't be new addition or removal of the existing places from the list.

Every new temple constructed has its own importance and uniqueness but they will not be equated with 108 divyadeshams.

Comment: this is unsourced opinion.

Comment: I have linked a well sourced answer in the answer. Read the answer carefully.

Comment: if the answer to another question answers this question, I'll delete this question.

Comment: @Sk No need of that. Both the questions are different and fine. A subset of that answer is also valid for this question. Other question was why there are no alwars but this is why no divyadesams. The answer is because there are no new alwars to sing praise of the temples in Nalayira Divyaprabandham. That answer serves as a source as well as an answer to the question created after reading the reason. That's why I added that answer as a source.